# No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: json, python-2.6

while running this script i am getting the following error...

```
ERROR: getTest failed.  No JSON object could be decoded
```

My code is:

```
import json
import urllib

class test:

    def getTest(self):
        try:
            url = 'http://www.exapmle.com/id/123456/'
            json_ = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
            self.id = json.loads(json_)
            print self.id
        except Exception, e:
            print "ERROR: getTest failed.  %s" % e
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ti = test()
    ti.getTest()
```

while opening this url "http://www.exapmle.com/id/123456/" in browser i am getting json format data, but why it is throwing an error?

Comment: Could you post what you get back from the URL so that we can see? In this case, I can only assume that the problem is with malformed JSON, and that's difficult to debug without the JSON in question.

Answer (score 0):

Print the `json_` before calling `json.loads()`. If there is in an error in your `url`, `urllib` does not necessarily throw an exception, it might just retrieve some error page (like with the provided url), that is not valid json.